# multiple dropdown list conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I hope someone can help me, I'm a newbie of JQuery. I'm trying to write a JQuery code for a script that mark the border of a dropdown box  #type if an option is selected in #age or if the option in #master is changed.

```
// condition 1 and condition 2
if($('#age :selected').text() !== '' || $('#master').change()) {

// perform the action
  $("#type").css("border","solid 1px red");

};
```

Unfortunately the condition related to the change doesn't work. As workaround I could create 2 different if for each condition, but I would like to keep together in the same if statement.Do you think is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property in order to save if a change event happened.
Hence, you can test against these properties:

```js
// add a listener to handle changes on dropdowns
$('#age, #master').on('change', function(e) {
    this.dataset.changed = true;
    if ($('#age').data('changed') == true && $('#master').data('changed') == true) {
        $("#type").css("border","solid 1px red");
        // reset....
        $('#age').data('changed', false);
        $('#master').data('changed', false);
    } else {
        $("#type").css("border","");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="age">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="master">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="type">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to `$('#master').change()`. Because it makes no sense without checking value of it that is default value or not. Another point is that it would be better to check value instead of text.

Anyway, I can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
age
<select id="age">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
</select> master
<select id="master">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="X">X</option>
        <option value="Y">Y</option>
</select> type
<select id="type">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#master, #age').change(function(e) {
  changeBorder(e);
});


function changeBorder(e) {

  if ($('#age').val() !== '' || (e.target.id === 'master' && $('#master').val() !== '')) {
    // perform the action
    $("#type").css("border", "solid 1px red");

  } else
    $("#type").css("border", "");

}
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/h6kxutfj/28/)